# Creating mocks for unit test - retrofit

Tags: java, api, mocking, retrofit

There is commandline app to show tomorrow's forecast using a public API

Sample output could be as follows:

```
Tomorrow (2019/05/01) in city XYZ:
Clear
Temp: 26.5 °C
Wind: 7.6 mph
Humidity: 61%
```

Question : How will you create a test case such that tests should not touch the real service and work without the Internet.

I tried creating the junit test for the same and its working fine till the time i am using the api directly.

Can someone please help how can i create a mock for my unit testing.

App.java

```
import api.ForecastServiceImpl;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Pass city name as an argument");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://www.metaweather.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);

        ForecastServiceImpl service = new ForecastServiceImpl(retrofit);
        System.out.println(service.getForecast(args[0], tomorrow));
    }
}
```

ForecastServiceImpl.java

```
package api;

import model.City;
import model.Forecast;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import util.PathDate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ForecastServiceImpl {

    private Retrofit retrofit;

    public ForecastServiceImpl(Retrofit retrofit) {
        this.retrofit = retrofit;
    }

    public String getForecast(String cityName, LocalDate date) throws IOException {
        PathDate pathDate = new PathDate(date);

        ForecastService service = retrofit.create(ForecastService.class);
        Call<List<City>> findCityCall = service.findCityByName(cityName.toLowerCase());
        City city = Objects.requireNonNull(findCityCall.execute().body())
                .stream()
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(String.format("Can't find city id for %s", cityName)));

        Call<List<Forecast>> forecastCall = service.getForecast(city.getWoeid(), pathDate);
        Forecast forecast = Objects.requireNonNull(forecastCall.execute().body())
                .stream()
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(String.format("Can't get forecast for %s", cityName)));

        return String.format("Weather on (%s) in %s:\n%s", pathDate, city.getTitle(), forecast);
    }
}
```

ForecastService.java

```
package api;

import model.City;
import model.Forecast;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;
import util.PathDate;

import java.util.List;

public interface ForecastService {

    @GET("/api/location/{city_id}/{date}/")
    Call<List<Forecast>> getForecast(@Path("city_id") Long cityId, @Path("date") PathDate date);

    @GET("/api/location/search/")
    Call<List<City>> findCityByName(@Query("query") String city);
}
```

City.java

```
package model;

public class City {

    private String title;
    private Long woeid;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getWoeid() {
        return woeid;
    }

    public void setWoeid(Long woeid) {
        this.woeid = woeid;
    }
}
```

Forecast.java

```
package model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Forecast {

    private Long id;
    @SerializedName("weather_state_name")
    private String weatherState;
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    private Double windSpeed;
    @SerializedName("the_temp")
    private Double temperature;
    private Integer humidity;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Forecast setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getWeatherState() {
        return weatherState;
    }

    public Forecast setWeatherState(String weatherState) {
        this.weatherState = weatherState;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    public Forecast setWindSpeed(Double windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public Forecast setTemperature(Double temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
        return this;
    }

    public Integer getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public Forecast setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s\nTemp: %.1f °C\nWind: %.1f mph\nHumidity: %d%%",
                weatherState, temperature, windSpeed, humidity);
    }
}
```

PathDate.java

```
package util;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class PathDate {

    private final LocalDate date;

    public PathDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    }
}
```

Utils.java

```
package util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Utils {

    public static byte[] readResourceFileToBytes(String filename) {
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename).toURI());
            fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        } catch (URISyntaxException|IOException|NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fileBytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to write the test for `getForecast` function right ?

Comment: Yes correct for getForecast

Comment: @DeepakPatankar can you please help me with a sample test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `service.getForecast(city.getWoeid(), pathDate);` returns us a `Call<List<Forecast>>` object. And when we call `execute` on this object then an actual API call is made. Since we don't want to do an actual API call, we can try mocking the `Call<List<Forecast>>` object.

We can mock the `Call` class like

```
Call<List<Forecast>> mockedListForeCast = mock(Call.class);
```

The above statement creates a mock object of `Call<List<Forecast>>`. We can use `when` to define what should happen when a method is called on the mocked object.

```
// here I am returning the singleton list, you can return a list of forecast
when(mockedListForeCast.execute()).thenReturn(Response.success(Collections.singletonList()));
```

The above line says that return an empty list of forecast when the execute function was called on the mocked object.

This way we are mocking the API response and we don't have to do an actual API call.

**Edit**:

You can also mock your retrofit API using [Retrofit Mock](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock) also.

Comment: Hey @user1873274, this is how I have written unit tests in my code. Can you please check whether this works for you also? You might need to change some part of lines in the above answer to suit your case.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak but one question, please explain this bit more as i am new to this.
Should i create a method mock where in i should use the call class for mocking and then defining the mocked output?

Comment: Sure, will add explanation

Comment: Hey @user1873274, I have updated my answer. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: i understood the concept and it was helpful. Do i need to create the mock method in the test class itself? or should it be in a separate class?
Sorry for asking too basic questions.

Comment: Thanks You @user1873274. The method mock() is part of Mockito class. If you are using some editor, then after typing mock(), the editor should provide the option of importing the required class(Mockito in this case).

Comment: import is fine. The point i was asking was that the complete implementation for mock should be done in the test class where i am writing my unit tests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222437/discussion-between-user1873274-and-deepak-patankar).